# Problems retrieving info from firebase and parsing with Retrofit and RxJava using REST

Tags: android, rest, firebase, retrofit, rx-android

Well, I've being struggling with Firebase response using the REST API response. The thing is I don't want to use Android's libs for Firebase and instead use raw rest api. Long story short, the response from Firebase is:

```
{
    "object1": {
        "param1": true,
        "param2": "05",
        "param3": "String",
    },
    "object2": {
        "param1": true,
        "param2": "09",
        "param3": "String",
    }
}
```

Retrofit interface:

```
public interface ApiCalls {
    @GET("/objects.json")
    Observable<List<MyObject>> getObjects();
}
```

Gson Builder, Retrofit Builder and RxJava:

```
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://my-service.firebaseio.com")
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();

    ApiCalls api = retrofit.create(ApiCalls.class);

    rx.Observable<List<MyObject>> call2 = api.getObjects();
    call2.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<MyObject>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.d("onCompleted", "Its completed");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.d("onError", e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<MyObject> MyObjects) {
                    Log.d("onNext", "NextItem");
                }
            });
```

When this is executed then I get the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

Is there anyway to solve this using RxJava in order to iterate the list of objects coming from the server? Since now I'm expecting an array but firebase's response is not an array, is there anyway to solve this?

Comment: the incoming JSON's root element is not an array, it's an object

Comment: Try using - Observable<Object> getObjects();

Comment: post your JSON ...............

Comment: This question it´s not about RxJava, the messages you post says that you´re trying to deserialize a jsonObject structure into JsonArray.

Comment: @VeereshCharantimath that is indeed the cause of the error: the JSON from Firebase is a map (`Map<String,Object>`), not a list. Care to post an answer?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the response from firebase is the same as I posted above:

{
    "object1": {
        "param1": true,
        "param2": "05",
        "param3": "String",
    },
    "object2": {
        "param1": true,
        "param2": "09",
        "param3": "String",
    }
}

Comment: Where are the POJO classes for the incoming JSON?

Comment: It would be: 
`Class MyObject { 
private boolean param1;
private String param2;
private String param3; }`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for your help. I was a Map<String,Object> indeed, so when I changed the expected type the issue was solved. Many thanks pal.

Comment: Did you consider using [FirebaseUI libs](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android)? Or you are heavy committed to don't use any Firebase lib at all? What about [RXFirebase lib](https://github.com/nmoskalenko/RxFirebase)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, thanks to this comment I could solve the issue:

> @VeereshCharantimath that is indeed the cause of the error: the JSON from Firebase is a map (Map), not a list. Care to post an answer? – Frank van Puffelen

After I modified the expected value of the response it started working:

Retrofit Api Calls

```
public interface ApiCalls {
    @GET("/objects.json")
    Observable<HashMap<String, MyObject>> getObjects();
}
```

RxJava

```
rx.Observable<HashMap<String, MyObject>> call2 = api.getObjects();
call2.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<HashMap<String, MyObject>>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                Log.d("onCompleted", "Its completed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Log.d("onError", e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(HashMap<String, MyObject> MyObjects) {
                Log.d("onNext", "NextItem");
            }
        });
```